# How do i convert JSON object to an array as above?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

FROM THIS TYPE

```
[
  { postId: 17 },
  { postId: 13 },
  { postId: 14 },
  { postId: 10 },
  { postId: 7 },
  { postId: 1 },
  { postId: 2 }
]
```

TO

```
[17, 13, 14, 10, 7, 1, 2]
```

I will query

```
SELECT * FROM posts Where post_id = 17, 13, 14, 10, 7, 1, 2
```

Thanks

SELECT * FROM posts Where post_id = 17, 13, 14, 10, 7, 1, 2

Comment: Oh, you would need to change the query to be `WHERE post_id IN(17, 13, 14, 10, 7, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let objs = [
  { postId: 17 },
  { postId: 13 },
  { postId: 14 },
  { postId: 10 },
  { postId: 7 },
  { postId: 1 },
  { postId: 2 }
]
let idsOnly = objs.map(obj => obj.postId);
```